# How to successfully emit KeyboardEvent "Ctrl+T" in AddonSDK

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, simulation, firefox-addon-sdk, keyboard-events

I'm needing some help on a small task on [Mozilla AddonSDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/SDK).

I am attempting to open the element hyperlink in a new tab while retaining browser session state and any JavaScript events.

This would mean a simple, grabbing of the element's `href` and `tab.open(href)` would be unlikely to provide ideal support.

It would be ideal to simulate the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[image: Left Mouse Click]</kbd> on a element to open the link in a new window.

Current attempt:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

exports.testOpenTabCommand = function(assert, done) {
  var html = 'data:text/html,<html><title></title><body><a href="http://example.com">Click</a></body></html>';
  var script = [
    'self.port.on("openNewTab", function(selector){',
    '  var elm = document.querySelector(selector);',
    '  var ev = new KeyboardEvent(\'keydown\', {',
    '    ctrlKey: true,',
    '    key: \'t\'',
    '  });',
    '  elm.dispatchEvent(ev);',
    '  self.port.emit("tabOpened", true);',
    '})'
  ].join('');

  tabs.open({
    url: html,
    onLoad: function(tab) {
      var worker = tab.attach({
        contentScript: script,
        contentScriptWhen: 'ready'
      });
      worker.port.on('tabOpened', function (){
        // first tab is `about:blank`
        // second tab is the html above
        // third tab should be the clicked link
        assert.equal(tabs.length, 3);
        tab.close(function(){
          done();
        });
      });
      worker.port.emit('openNewTab', 'a');
    }
  });
};

require('sdk/test').run(exports);
```

I appreciate your answers and comments.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood properly, it seems to me that you just need to add `inBackground` property when you open the link using [tabs.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs):

```
tabs.open({
  url: href,
  inBackground: true
});
```

If that is not the case, let me know and we'll figure out alternatives.

**Updated (see the comments):**

In order to properly synthetize keystrokes and mouse events, especially in the new version of Firefox with e10s, we need to do something more complex, like:

```
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
const { OS } = require("sdk/system/runtime");
const { getTabBrowserForTab } = require("sdk/tabs/utils");
const { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");

const { Cc, Ci } = require("chrome");

const remote = (f) => "data:application/javascript," + encodeURIComponent(`(${f}())`);

const globalMessageManager = Cc["@mozilla.org/globalmessagemanager;1"]
                              .getService(Ci.nsIMessageListenerManager);

// it would be better put the code of the content function in an
// external module, and then use `framescript/manager` to load it
globalMessageManager.loadFrameScript(remote(function() {
  let domWindowUtils = this.content.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                       .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);

  this.addMessageListener("myaddon:click", ({target, json}) => {
    let { accelKey, selector } = json;
    let node = this.content.document.querySelector(selector);
    let { top, left } = node.getBoxQuads()[0].bounds;

    // Simulate the click with the proper accel key
    let accel = domWindowUtils["MODIFIER_" + accelKey];
    domWindowUtils.sendMouseEvent("mousedown", left + 1, top + 1, 0, 1, 0, accel);
    domWindowUtils.sendMouseEvent("mouseup", left + 1, top + 1, 0, 1, accel);

    target.sendAsyncMessage("myaddon:clicked");
  });
}), true);

const synthesizeClickFor = (tab, selector) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  let { selectedBrowser } = getTabBrowserForTab(viewFor(tab));

  globalMessageManager.addMessageListener("myaddon:clicked", function listener({json}) {
    this.removeMessageListener("myaddon:clicked", listener);

    resolve();
  });

  let accelKey = OS === "Darwin" ? "META" : "CONTROL";
  selectedBrowser.messageManager.sendAsyncMessage("myaddon:click", { selector, accelKey });
});

exports.testOpenTabCommand = function(assert, done) {
  var html = "data:text/html,<html><title></title><body><a href='http://mozilla.org'>Click</a></body></html>";

  tabs.open({
    url: html,
    onLoad: function(tab) {
      synthesizeClickFor(tab, "a").then(() => {
        assert.ok(tabs.length, 3, "expected 3 tabs")

        // you need to close also the 3rd tab
        tabs[2].close(() => tab.close(done));
      });
    }
  });
};

require('sdk/test').run(exports);
```

This simulate the left click plus the accel key (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> (MODIFIER_CONTROL) on Win / Linux, <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> (MODIFIER_META) on OS X). You can also synthetize keys in a similar way, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindowUtils#sendKeyEvent%28%29

Comment: Hey @ZER0 thanks for attempting, this soultion does work, but doesn't fully complete the problem. Imagine trying to click on a <div onclick="window.location = 'http://example.com'"></div>

Comment: I tried to address the end result that seemed you had in mind from what you wrote; that's because it was the simplest solution *if* it was what you wanted. But you want to have a sort of integration test infrastructure, where you want to simulate keystrokes and mouse events, and to do so you need more privilege than what content scripts provides. Plus, now that firefox has content and chrome in two separate process, it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Wow ZER0 that if a fantastic answer.